# cin.ignore definition doesn't show optional parameters, but it can be called without them?

Tags: visual-c++

I was looking at a definition, which is the following:

istream&  ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );

How is it that I can then call as cin.ignore(), where I think that it just eats the next character. Or am I looking at the wrong definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses default parameters. If you call cin.ignore(), what you get is cin.ignore(1, EOF).

EDIT:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/

Comment: Ok, your edit clears up the default parameters. I had not learned about those yet.

Comment: default parameters are part of the language structure. When you see an equal sign in a function prototype it means that parameter will use the value to the right of the equal sign by default if no value is supplied.  I added a link to a brief tutorial which explains this in more detail